# Extracting NSManagedObject attribute values from NSOrderedSet

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I have an initializer that takes an array of `Strings` as a parameter. Rather than re-write the class and risk breaking things, I'd prefer to feed the initializer what it wants.

I'm trying to extract `NSStrings` from `NSManagedObjects` stored in an `NSOrderedSet`.

Here's what I've tried:

```
    let soundsToPlay = sequenceToPlay.sounds as NSOrderedSet
    for element in soundsToPlay {
        // this prints out the object in console
        print("\(element)")
        // this, doesn't give me accessors for the sound object
        // print("\(element.fileName)")
    }
```

I'm missing something basic, but I'm not sure what. How would I enumerate the objects in an NSOrderedSet and extract the value of the attributes for the entities contained within the set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest reading the documentation on KVC (Key Value Coding) as you can write this as one line of code:

```
let filenameArray = soundsToPlay.valueForKey("fileName").array()
```

The call to `valueForKey` will return an `NSOrderedSet` of the string and then you can convert that to an array with a call to `array()`

Comment: WOW! That is SLICK! Thank you for showing me that shortcut. My solution was turning into a Rube Goldberg contraption.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I was missing a step:

```
let soundsToPlay = sequenceToPlay.sounds as NSOrderedSet
for element in soundsToPlay {
    // I have to tell the compiler what type of thing my thing is
    let whatIWantToAccess = element as! MyObjectINeedAccessorsFor
    print("\(whatIWantToAccess.fileName)")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats probably because compiler thinks that "element" is instance of NSManagedObject and it does not have fileName , try explicit type-casting , something like

```
for element: YourClass in soundsToPlay
```